# How to use https input with ffmpeg "amovie" filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm applying a filter on my audio file before adding it to the video. This is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video-input.mp4 -f lavfi -i "amovie=audio.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=92:d=2" -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 video-output.mp4
```

I would like to use a https input:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video-input.mp4 -f lavfi -i "amovie=https://www.xxxx.com/audio.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=92:d=2" -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 video-output.mp4
```

But this is the error I get:

```
[Parsed_amovie_0 @ 0x55da3a414a40] Failed to avformat_open_input 'https'
[lavfi @ 0x55da3a436660] Error initializing filter 'amovie' with args 'https://www.xxxx.com/audio.mp3:loop=0'
amovie=https://www.xxxx.com/audio.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB: No such file or directory
```

From the "amovie" documentation on ffmpeg:

```
filename: The name of the resource to read (not necessarily a file; it can also be a device or a stream accessed through some protocol).
```

How can I use a https input in my audio filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL has to be escaped as `:` is a special character, as is `/`. So, for bash, use

```
amovie=https\\\:\/\/www.xxxx.com\/audio.mp3
```

Comment: Great, it works ! Can you please confirm that it should be this instead: `amovie=https\:\/\/www.xxxx.com\/audio.mp3`

Comment: This worked for me: `"amovie='https\:\/\/www.xxxx.com\/audio.mp3'"`, with double quotes around the filter and single quotes around the url.

Comment: @Gyan i am also having same problem my url is auth.php?langs=en&txt=meena&f.mp3 how to escaped the url its not working in amovie parameter giving the same error.

Comment: I cannot get this to work with UDP streams. No errors, just fails to output anything using `ffprobe -f lavfi "amovie='udp\:\/\/@238.0.0.1:1234',ashowinfo" -show_frames`

Comment: @MichaelBrown Did you get this to work? I am trying to do something similar, but with an SRT (Secure Reliable Transport) stream instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please wrap the URL in the single quotes and escape the `:`

```
ffmpeg -y -i video-input.mp4 -f lavfi -i "amovie='https\://www.xxxx.com/audio.mp3':loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,afade=in:st=0:d=1,afade=out:st=92:d=2" -shortest -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 video-output.mp4
```